Micronaut JWT authentication
Is it possible to authenticate user same as in "MICRONAUT JWT AUTHENTICATION VIA COOKIES" but manually after a new account has been submitted via custom sign up form? I want to redirect user to the homepage but already signed in with JWT token set in cookies, same as in the predefined "/login" controller response.
